# Multiline JS expressions inside JSX are forbidden

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tslint

I use tslint to check my react typescript app. I created this and it works but i get this message from tslint: "Multiline JS expressions inside JSX are forbidden". I wonder how I should change the code so I don't get tslint message. The code where it occurs is:

```
<MDBCol size="12">
              {pubItem ? (
                <table className="pubDetails w-100">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th className="pubHead w-25">Publicatie ID:</th>
                      <td className="pubItems w-25">
                        {pubItem.publicationId ? pubItem.publicationId : "Geen"}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th className="pubHead">Publicatie Naam:</th>
                      <td className="pubItems">
                        {pubItem.publicationName
                          ? pubItem.publicationName
                          : "Geen"}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            ) : null}
         </MDBCol>
```

Comment: So what's your question? Either turn off tslint, change rules so they match your requirements or force it to ignore this. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/

Comment: I wonder how I should change the code so I don't get tslint message.

Comment: Doesn't TSLint point exactly on the expression it's telling about?

Answer (score 1):

`{pubItem.publicationName ? pubItem.publicationName : "Geen"}` Maybe it's assignment problem of ts.

You could try create tslint.json in your project tslint.json.You can configure it in this file. [For Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2nGc.png)