# Multi-line JavaScript inside JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tslint

### Is it possible to write a multiline js code in JSX?

```
return (
      <b>{
      const a = props.users.find((user) => user.id === post.userId)
      console.log(a) // I want to console.log
      return a
      }</b>
);
```

Comment: Look this post please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375422/multiline-js-expressions-inside-jsx-are-forbidden

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do multi-line JavaScript code, you can wrap your JS code with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), for example:

```
  <>
    {(() => {
      const a = [1, 2, 3].find((el) => el === 2)
      // as much code as you want ...
      // ...
      // ...
      console.log(a)
    })()}
  </>
```

Just in case you don't know, `<>` & `</>` are called React fragments, you can use any valid JSX element you want, for example, you can use instead `<div>`, `<b>`, `<p>` or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks, man, you really helped me a lot!!

Comment: Please don't. How about you pull the code a few lines up, out of the markup and only `return <b>{a}</b>`.